# How to identify rules satisfying a certain condition based on events

Tags: design, microservices, event-programming, problem-solving

I am working on a microservice, in an event driven world, where I have tens of 1000s of rules configured which depend on data type A, B, C, D and so on.

As soon as an event arrives I want to be able to identify which rules are dependent on this data and execute those rules.

The current approach which I am thinking which is very basic is while startup create a look-up table which creates a map of data type (A/B/C/D) to list of rules which are dependent on this data type.

Is there a better way to do it? My way will solve the problem but I just wanted to explore if there exists a better way to achieve this with high throughput.

Example of a rule would be:

> A > 23 & B == True & C.age >= 18

or something much more complex

Thanks.

Comment: This is a pretty big subject, and I'm not sure which aspect of it you are struggling with. In general, you are looking to implement a "rules engine" -- you can search for that term and see where that gets you. Then come back to us when you have questions that we can actually answer.

Comment: @BobDalgleish I have looked at BRMS and Rules Engine already. This question specifically concerns how to know which rules to evaluate, as quickly as possible, based on certain conditions.

Comment: That is **exactly** what rules engines do.

Answer (score 1):

This is solved by storing the rules in a tree, same approach as a [prefix tree](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

Assuming you have a way to identify which classes are used by which rule:

For every rule

Generate the unique list of dependent classes, sort ascending. *Then* insert into a tree representing this ordered list

```
()
() - A
() - - B
() - - C
() - B - C
```

Don't know how to do trees here... Under the root you have node A. Node A holds a list of rules just using class A. Under A there is node B holding all the rules dependent on A and B. Under A there is also node C and node C is holding all the rules dependent on A and C.

Upon arrival of event, generate the same ordered list of classes. Walk the tree and execute or invoke or run the rules on the event.

**However** - Is there a requirement to have a single event channel? Can that be partitioned to not have this problem?